# Unable to access property of a nested UserControl

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, user-controls

I have one UserControl nested inside the other UserControl, something like that:

```
<uc:MyControl1>
  <uc:MyControl2 Name="cheese"/>
</uc:MyControl2>
```

uc:MyControl2 contains a DP *Name*.
And inside `uc:MyControl`1 I am exposing `uc:MyControl2` using a standard property:

```
   public uc:MyControl1 ExposedMyProperty1 {get{return MyProperty1}}
```

But I still can't access it form the `uc:MyControl1` :

```
<uc:MyControl1 ExposedMyProperty1.Name="Milk">
  <uc:MyControl2/>
</uc:MyControl2>
```

Intellisense shows only the properties of the UserControl, but not of my derived version of the UserControl. Meaning I see all the properties which comes from the UserControl, but don't see DP I have defined. So it looks like I am getting a UserControl instead of `uc:MyControl1`.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question. The answer is: you can't access nested properties from you xaml. I don't know what is the reason for WPF not allowing that..

The answer comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/834391/230506)

Answer (score 1):

In your code sample you only expose a getter and not a setter. That *may* be your problem.

Try this:

```
public string ExposedMyProperty1 { get {return MyProperty1; } set {MyProperty1 = value;}}
```

But your code sample appears to be incomplete. For you say you are exposing a `DependencyProperty`, and your property is only a regular property. So this may not be the solution to your problem.

Comment: I am exposing a DP of uc:MyControl2 using a standart property. Adding setter doesn't help (tried already).

Comment: @Vitalij: What error do you get? And can you update your code sample to be more complete?

Comment: I am sorry! I have missed two very important points and without them a question doesn't make much sense. I have just updated my question.