# WPF/XAML Intuitive UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

what steps must be done to make a user control, to work in such order:

```
 <local:MyUserControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <local:MyUserControl.Items> 
                <local:MyUserControl.Item Name="{Binding Name}"/>
            </local:MyUserControl.Items>
 </local:MyUserControl>
```

I know that for ItemsSource I need to create DependencyProperty, but what for the part which is inside MyUserControl.

Example:

Look below is an example how I used to do it.

This is called MyUserControl

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="3,3,3,3"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainPage:

```
<local:MyUserControl />
```

As you can see in this scenario, MyUserControl is not universal, it can be used properly ONLY if I have ItemsSource called Items, and inside of it there is a property called Name.

My Intention is to create flexible MyUserControl.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the usercontrol has a listbox inside that uses the itemssource, make it like so: `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />`.

Comment: Now, here's a question for you: Why does your XAML fragment set both `ItemsSource` and `Items` on your usercontrol? Are they two completely different things?

Comment: They relate to each other. I would like that MyUserControl have as many items as Items(ObservableCollection) has, and has its names being given in Name. I asked what steps needs to be done to make a user control working in such a way. Because when I just put it in xaml just like it is I get an error the member Items is not recognized or is not accessible

Comment: I would not try to combine the two. That will get ugly. WPF doesn't try. I think you really want a subclass of ItemsControl.

Comment: The "correct" way is the consumer can give you a CompositeCollection.

Comment: Ok I found an answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834391/can-i-use-xaml-to-set-a-nested-property-property-of-the-value-of-a-property-of